# Code hangs while trying to "while (!radio.available())" and checking button input one after the other repeatedly

Tags: while-loop, arduino-uno

I am trying to build a wireless LED controller using "nrf24l01" wireless modules and I get stuck. I want to have a periodical connection test to confirm that the receiver is still "there". I have that part of the code working well on its own: I transmit, wait to listen, receiver responds and connection is confirmed. Then I tried to add a button press check to run while the wireless test isn't running, again, alone the button test works and serial monitor shows button presses as expected, but when I try to do both processes one after the other the code hangs on listening to the receivers response on line - "while (!radio.available());". I have both processes on separate functions that I call in the main loop. I comment one of them out to test the other individually.

---

EDIT: It seems my explanation may be a little confusing. I'll try to simplify: If I run the radio transmission code alone (with no modifications) the code works (Messages are sent and received). If I add a button press detection part to the transmission code, transmission freezes (Message is sent but ignores receiving any further responses, even if responded repeatedly). If I run the button press part of the code alone it works. Why do those two parts of the code interfere with each other?

---

[Both transmitter and receiver code uploaded to Google drive.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nT6alNea18KdabdbZqIFSW-yATXY2Pwk)

Why is the transmitter hanging or interrupted be a second process? Can I fix something in my code to make it work or is there a better way to structure the code?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Transmitter code:

```
    //Wireless Transmitter
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include "RF24.h"

//Wireless RF24 Config
RF24 radio(9, 10);  //previously (7, 8)
const byte Address[][6] = {"1","2"};  //1-write, 2-read

  //Settings--
//System Settings
const long ConnCheckInt = 1000;
const long ListenFor = 5000;
int RadioSetup = 1; //Enable/Disable radio functions 1/0.
const long SystemStart = 1000; //delays time related process startup

  //Test mode settings--
int TestMode = 1; //Serial monitor on/off - 1/0.
int TestDelay = 100; //test mode delay to make sense of the data flow.
int RadioTest = 1;
int IO_Test = 1;
int ButtonTest = 1;

//Connection test variables
int WiFiHandshakeSendCode = 100;
int WiFiHandshakeSuccessCode = 101;
int WiFiHandshakeReceiveCode = 0;
unsigned long ConnStart = 0;
unsigned long ConnCheckAgain = 100;
int RecOfflineCount = 1;
int RecOffAllowed = 20; //how many times in a row can connection fail.
int StateFree = 1;
unsigned long ListenStart = 0;
unsigned long ListenEnd = 0;

//Status LED
int StatusLEDPin = 3;
int StatusLEDTog = 0;
const long StatLEDOnTime = 100;
unsigned long StatLEDStart = 0;

//Delays
int delay1 = 5; //radio delay
int delay2 = 1;

//Inputs
int ChannelIn_1 = 2;  // button
int ChannelIn_1S = 0;
int ChannelIn_1Last = 0;

int InputUpdate = 0;

void setup() {
  if(RadioSetup == 1){
    radio.begin();
    radio.setChannel(115); //Up to 126 channels
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX);
    radio.setDataRate(RF24_250KBPS); //250 is the lowest for best range.
    radio.openWritingPipe(Address[1]);
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, Address[2]);
  }
  if(TestMode == 1){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Transmitter Start");
  }
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  ConnCheck();  // If both ConnCheck and CheckInputs are enabled the Code hangs on tab b_ line 26.
  CheckInputs();  // If either one is commented out, they work fine alone.
}

void ConnCheck(){
  if(millis() >= ConnCheckAgain){
    ConnTest();
    ConnStart = millis();
    ConnCheckAgain = ConnStart + ConnCheckInt + ListenFor;
    if(TestMode == 1 && RadioTest == 1){
      Serial.print("Next Check: ");
      Serial.println(ConnCheckAgain);
    }
  }
}

void ConnTest(){
  if(TestMode == 1 && RadioTest == 1){
    Serial.println("Checking connection... ");
    WiFiHandshakeReceiveCode = 0;
    Serial.print("Read before: ");
    Serial.println(WiFiHandshakeReceiveCode);
  }
  delay(delay1);
  radio.stopListening();
  radio.write(&WiFiHandshakeSendCode, sizeof(WiFiHandshakeSendCode));

  delay(delay1);
  radio.startListening();
  Serial.println("Before hang.");
  while (!radio.available());    // Code hangs here.  <----
  Serial.println("After hang.");
  radio.read(&WiFiHandshakeReceiveCode, sizeof(WiFiHandshakeReceiveCode));

  Serial.print("Read: ");
  Serial.println(WiFiHandshakeReceiveCode);

  if(WiFiHandshakeReceiveCode == WiFiHandshakeSuccessCode){
    RecOfflineCount = 1;
    digitalWrite(StatusLEDPin, LOW);
    StatusLEDTog = 0;
    if(TestMode == 1 && RadioTest == 1){
      Serial.println("Connection Test Complete: ");
      Serial.println("Receiver online.");
    }
    radio.stopListening();
  }

  else{
    if(TestMode == 1 && RadioTest == 1){
      Serial.println("Disconnected");
      radio.stopListening();
    }
    if(RecOfflineCount == RecOffAllowed){
      StatusLEDToggle();
    }
    RecOfflineCount = RecOfflineCount + 1;
  }
}

void CheckInputs(){
  if(StateFree == 1){
    ChannelIn_1S=digitalRead(ChannelIn_1);
    if(ChannelIn_1S == HIGH && ChannelIn_1Last != ChannelIn_1S){
      ChannelIn_1Last = ChannelIn_1S;
      if(ButtonTest == 1){
        InputUpdate = 1;
      }
    }
    else if(ChannelIn_1S == LOW && ChannelIn_1Last != ChannelIn_1S){
      ChannelIn_1Last = ChannelIn_1S;
      if(ButtonTest == 1){
        InputUpdate = 1;
      }
    }
    if(TestMode == 1 && ButtonTest == 1 && InputUpdate == 1){
      Serial.print("Channel 1 Input: ");
      Serial.println(ChannelIn_1S);
      InputUpdate = 0;
    }
  }
}

void StatusLEDToggle(){
  if (StatusLEDTog == 0){
    digitalWrite(StatusLEDPin, HIGH);
    StatusLEDTog = 1;
  }
  else if (StatusLEDTog == 1){
    digitalWrite(StatusLEDPin, LOW);
    StatusLEDTog = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1. [edit] and tag a language. 2. It is preferred that you post the code in your question. Just the relevant code. See: how to create a [mcve].

Comment: I added the code to my post. I am not skilled enough to make it any more compact and still have it work. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Jonny Mopp, So now my question wont get any attention because I have a -1 vote? :/

Comment: I'm not familiar with the nrf24l01, but a quick look at the code shows it uses SPI. According to the [Arduino docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI), it looks like SPI uses pin 10 for SS. You are also trying to use that. Try changing that: `RF24 radio(7, 8);`

Comment: Thank you Johnny Mopp for your recommendation. I tried switching the pins back to 7 and 8. As before, the transmission part of the code works alone, when I add the button press detection the transmission freezes and does not accept any responses. Does anyone have an example code where they use a transmission device along with button presses? How do you time everything?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `while (!radio.available());` is stuck is because your transceiver is not receiving anything. Try the following to debug:

- You may transmit using another transceiver to this device and then continue your testing.
- You may use another Arduino and transceiver which is continuously transmitting the data/ or modify the code in a way such that only when you press the button it transmits some data.

```
    // Upon Button Press
    const char text[] = "Hello World";
    radio.write(&text, sizeof(text));
```

- In your case, the receiver would be in a blocking mode until it receives some signal. You could also implement a timeout to wait until a period of time to receive a data, if not, proceed further with the other lines of your code (you may print a debug message that the signal was not received).

P.S: I was also looking at the code you have posted, it looks like its incomplete as I could not find any reference to `TestMode, ButtonTest` being initialized.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tested further by setting my other arduino (receiver) to spam the response multiple times, meaning that if the transmitter should continue with the code once it receives a response, but it doesn't. Once it sends the first message and starts to wait for a response, it is waiting unresponsive.

Comment: Also, if the issue is that it doesn't get the response from the receiver, why does it work when I disable the part of the code that is supposed to check button presses? If it's just the [transmit, wait for response, response received, wait for some time, try again] part of the code, the communication works perfectly.

Comment: I did try to add a timeout to waiting but didn't succeed or figure out how. However, if I add a timeout successfully, it would just cancel the wait and never confirm if the receiver is there or not. How can I structure a code that checks multiple inputs/button presses and checks if the receiver is still there like every 5 minutes?

Comment: The "TestMode" and "ButtonTest" are initialized in the beginning of the code under the title "Test mode settings". After that they are used in different places in the code so that if I want to turn of "serial prints" for button presses or turn of "serial print" lines completely I can set TestMode=0 and all the "serial print" lines will be skipped. I tried to add settings toggles essentially to control different parts of the code, I tried removing them completely but they did not affect the issue.